# unknown variable 'default-storage-engine=myisam'

Tags: mysql, myisam, storage-engines

I am trying to configure Mysql (Ver 14.15 Distrib 6.0.8-alpha, for Win64) to use MyISAM as the default storage engine on Windows 7. I've created C:\my.cnf with the following contents:

```
[mysql]
default-storage-engine=myisam
```

And after restarting the mysql service and attempting to run mysql from the console, I get the following error message:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'default-storage-engine=myisam'
```

I've been working from tutorials and have copied and pasted the above directly into my my.cnf file.

I've tried a combination of the following:

```
set default-storage-engine=myisam
storage-engine=mysiam
set storage-engine=mysiam
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried changing it and it worked for me.

What I did was simply changed the value from "INNODB" to "MYISAM" in [mysqld] group as follows

from

```
default-storage-engine=INNODB
```

to

```
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
```

Note: its `[mysqld]` group not `[mysql]` group. [mysql] group is for MySQL client, not for server.

Alternatively, you can change default storage engine by executing

```
"set global storage_engine=MYISAM"
```

You will not be required to restart the server in this case.

Hope it helps....

Comment: Following these instructions removed the error, but did not successfully alter the default storage engine. The output of `show engines;` still says my default storage engine is InnoDB. Is it possible that it's being overwritten in another config file?

Comment: can't see the result of show engines? Did you restarted your MySQL server after doing changes?

Comment: I altered the file C:\my.cnf to say: `[mysqld] 
default-storage-engine=MYISAM` and then restarted the mysql service and logged in using a non-root account and ran `show engines;`

Comment: I guess you are working on Windows. In Windows you must have installed MySQL somewhere in Program Files, I guess. Now go to this installation folder, you will see a file "my.ini". You need to make changes there. In [mysqld] group, you will already find this variable with name default-storage-engine=INNODB, simply replace this INNODB to MYISAM. Then restart your server.

Comment: [Posted before I read reply above] My suspicion was correct: There was a my.ini in my MySQL folder that contained the line `default-storage-engine=InnoDB` - once I changed this to MyISAM, I achieved the desired effect. Thanks for your replies, shubhansh.